# How to build database table structure for customer service products in mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a cable customer project database structure in this project customers(subscribers) use service products like (settopbox, modem, etc 3 or 4 service products with different attributes). Below is my database table structure :-

**Customer Table**

customer_id,name,address, phone_no, etc

customer_settopbox table
customer_modem table
packages table

my question is :-
1. Is it good to build separate table for each device and allot to customer.

or any other method is there for this. because each device has their own attributes like settopbox has VCNO, SerialNo etc modem has other attributes.
I will be vary thankful.

Comment: it is generally not good to build a separate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add all common product fields to product table.
- All custom fileds can be placed to product_custom_attribute table.

you can use structure like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `phone_no` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `product_type` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);



CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK product type  product_type id_idx` (`type`),
    KEY `FK product customer_id  customer id_idx` (`customer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK product customer_id  customer id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
        REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `FK product type  product_type id` FOREIGN KEY (`type`)
        REFERENCES `product_type` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;




CREATE TABLE `product_custom_attribute` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK product_custom_attribute product_id  product id_idx` (`product_id` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `FK product_custom_attribute product_id  product id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
        REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

If you do not familiar with `FOREIGN KEY`s use this one

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `phone_no` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK product type  product_type id_idx` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `product_custom_attribute` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK product_custom_attribute product_id  product id_idx` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `product_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I have right now only two types of device like settopbox and internet modem and I need to store there values of with different attributes like settopbox has VCNo, SerialNo, ChipId, Model and modem has different like ModelNo PinNo etc

Comment: my structure is completely fits your requirements

Comment: you are right. Thank you very much. but how to find customer product

Comment: added   `customer_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL` to product table should i help you with query?

Comment: yes plz help me I will be vary thankful

Answer (score 0):

Don't build a table for each device. Instead, you can have a table that is called "device attributes" that has the attributes for each device. it will be easier to refer to that table and take the attributes for each device. In the customer's table, you can refer to a device.

Comment: each customer can have more than one device and where to store device attributes values for each customer

Comment: @RammeharSharma that will be no problem. the customer_settopbox table, customer_modem table and packages table can record each entry, and you can search all the products that a certain user has, then check the product's properties from the properties table.

Comment: can u create an example with table structure

Comment: @RammeharSharma in case you are wondering how to keep the records in the "device attributes" table, you can place all the properties in one field and then use array explode and implode functions to access them. (maybe because the number of attributes may differ.)

Comment: @RammeharSharma, the table may have just two columns: device name and device attributes. In the attributes, use the above comment to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how you see the future. If there is a know number of products which will **NEVER** be expanded, you can have additional columns within the customer's table. If, on the other hand, the list of products is prone to change in the future, having a separate table with (essentially) 3 columns:

```
- Customer ID (reference to the customer's table record)
- Product type
- Product status
```

This will give you all the needed flexibility while keeping things simple.

Comment: each customer can have more than one device and where to store device attributes values for each customer

Comment: The additional table may have as many columns as you need. In my example I included the basic three, but you can (and perhaps should) add as many as needed.

Comment: customer device table like customer_device_id, customer_id, device_name,VCNo,CardNo,SerialNo, etc, I don't know how to store different device with different attributes and there value for each customer

Comment: My friend, I don't know what your business requirements are. The only thing I can tell you is that you may include a device_id (auto-increment within the table), customer_id, device_type_id, device_status, creation_timestamp,last_update_timestamp, last_update_by,... The rest will depend on your business needs.